# Hibernate Joined Table on save return child records already exists

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using spring data (Hibernate).

**User model:**

```
@Entity
@Table (name="users")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)

public class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.Auto)
  private UUID id;

  @Column(unique=true)
  private String email;

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(
    name="users_skills",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "skill_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  )
  private Collection<Skill> skills;

  // Getter's Setter's
}
```

**Skill Model**:

```
@Entity
@Table (name="skills")
public class Skill {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.Auto)
    private UUID id;

    @Column(unique=true)
    private String name;

    // Getter's Setter's
}
```

**User Repository**

```
@Respository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, UUID> {
    boolean existsByEmail(String email);
}
```

**User Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("user/")
public class UserController {

    final private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowire
    public UserController(final UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @PostMapping("signup/")
    public ResponseEntity<?> signup(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {
        if (this.userRepository.existsByEmail(user.getEmail())) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }
        User newUser = this.userRepository.save(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(newUser, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

**Request Body**

```
{ 
   "email": "dummy@exmaple.com", 
   "skills": [{"name": "C++"}, {"name":"Java"}]
}
```

It works if the skill is not exists in database, if I try to attach existing skill I got following error

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uk_85woe63nu9klkk9fa73vf0jd0"
  Detail: Key (name)=(C++) already exists.
```

is there any way around to attach existing skill with user, thanks in advance.

**Possible Solutions**

- I pass the skill in request body and its start working.

```
{ 
   "email": "dummy@exmaple.com", 
   "skills": [{"name": "C++", "id": 1}, {"name":"Java", "id": 2}]
}
```

- There is another way around, pre-save I need to find skill by id and add it to user skill collection (Suggested by @Rohit).

Comment: find the skill by name and attach it to the user object before saving it.

Comment: It works, I was thinking may be there is hibernate annotation that automatically handle this :)
Thanks